# How to create a page with URL in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

The application is receiving from the server an HTML file.

This data (responseToPost) can be shown on the page like this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.responseToPost }} />
```

I was wondering if it's possible to create a new URL where to show this data?

The html file has this format:

```
<hr />
<p>title: "my-title"</p>
<h2 id="123">a....
```

and I want that the created page to be like: `localhost:3000/my-title` and show the HTML on that page.

Is it something possible? What approach should I use?

Comment: This is generally referred to as "routing". Check out [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly doable with **React Router**.

You'll need to pull in the `npm` dependency to your project, then you can set up your route, `my-title` as a `<Route>`, then render whatever you like on that page, in your case `responseToPost`.

Obviously setup requires a few more steps than just declare a `<Route>` but the official documentation is very good: [React Router official doc](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for that. I would suggest having a special route for it, let's say `/pages/` (code simplified):

```js
// On your Routes (usually App.js) page:
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
  <Route path="/pages/:pageslug" component={Page} />
</Router>

const PAGES = {
  'my-title': "<div>...</div>"
};

// Page.js
export function Page({ match }) {
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: PAGES[match.params.pageslug] }} />  
  );
}
```